# Steam won't start on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: steam

Linux noob here.

I just installed Steam and when I run "steam" in the terminal it outputs this:

```
    priam@priam:~$ steam
    tar: This does not look like a tar archive
    xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
    tar: Child returned status 1
    tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
    find: ‘/home/priam/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
```

I tried searching for solutions but I couldn't find anything that helps and I don't want to use Windows again. Thanks

Comment: How did you installed Steam? And where, Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: @MichaelBay i installed it from the ubuntu software app and i got ubuntu off the ubuntu site

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got steam from the [steam website](http://store.steampowered.com/about/). It works perfectly. The programs in the software center can get quite outdated.

Why do you not want to use steam on windows? Because not all windows games can be played on linux.

Comment: i tried installing it from the steam website, the same error happens

Comment: and i don't want to use windows because it's pretty slow with my setup, i have a dual boot with windows but i want to use linux when possible

Comment: could you post the output of `which steam`?

Comment: ok, i'm an idiot, i forgot to uninstall steam before installing it from the official site. it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir /home/$(whoami)/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
```

worked great for me

Fixed:

```
$ mkdir /home/$(whoami)/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 19.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
```